# BeginExecuteNonQuery without EndExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("blahblah;Asynchronous Processing=true;")
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("someProcedureName", sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);

        command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I never call EndExecuteNonQuery.

Two questions, first will this block because of the using statements or any other reason?  Second, will it break anything?  Like leaks or connection problems?  I just want to tell sql server to run a stored procedure, but I don't want to wait for it and I don't even care if it works.  Is that possible?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: hmm, I guess I will go with the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, but it just seems like a waste that I have to use a thread in my application to monitor something I don't care about.  I just want to issue a command to sqlServer and forget it.  It seems that I have some fundamental misunderstanding of how connections to the db work because I really don't understand why it's not possible to do this.  Anyone have a link that explains why this is not possible?

Comment: BeginExecuteNonQuery uses the ThreadPool anyway, so you're not doing anything it wouldn't do otherwise.  The reason you can't rely on this is that since BeginExecuteNonQuery doesn't block until the query finishes, you might close the connection while the query is still running in the background.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This won't work because you're closing the connection while the query is still running.  The best way to do this would be to use the threadpool, like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("blahblah;Asynchronous Processing=true;") {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("someProcedureName", sqlConnection)) {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
});
```

In general, when you call Begin_Whatever_, you usually must call End_Whatever_ or you'll leak memory.  The big exception to this rule is Control.BeginInvoke.

Comment: But the procedure is indeed completing.  I can see the records it inserts later.  ???

Comment: But you can't rely on it always completing before you close the connection.  You may get subtle and hard-to-reproduce bugs in producation when the server load is high.

Comment: @SLaks - your solution works quite well but do you know of any performance (dis)advantages to using the BeginExecuteNonQuery? I guess I can see that this method would require the creation of multiple background threads but I wouldn't really say that's a performance hit.

Comment: I thought on this a bit more and my conclusion is because the call is synchronous the background thread will be waiting and consuming resources during that time. In terms of efficiency and performance I'd say the solution provided by Remus Rusanu is more optimal.

Comment: @n00b: Correct.  My version is just simpler.

Answer (score 11):

1. You can't close the connection after you submit the BeginExceuteNotQuery. It will abort the execution. Remove the using block.
2. In order to close the connection, you must know when the call has completed. For that you **must** call EndExecuteNonQuery, usually from a callback:

.

```
command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(delegate (IAsyncResult ar) {
   try { command.EndExecuteNonQuery(ar); }
   catch(Exception e) { /* log exception e */ }
   finally { sqlConnection.Dispose(); }
   }, null);
```

If you want to submit a query and don't care about the results, [see Asynchronous T-SQL execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) for a reliable pattern that ensures execution even if client diconnects or crashes.

Comment: The code in this answer works fine, but be wary if you pass in the SqlCommand as the AsyncState.  It caused a hard to correct memory leak, basically a circular GC reference.  Again, nothing in this answer is wrong, just hoping to save people some time diagnosing.

Comment: @Zachary: That shouldn't cause any problems; the GC can handle that just fine.  And you're doing that anyway with the closure.

Comment: @SLaks: That's what I thought when I first wrote it, the IAsyncResult that was passed into the delegate held on to the reference to the SqlCommand. "Shouldn't" is the operative word there.

Comment: @ZacharyYates: The .Net GC doesn't have any problems with circular references, period.  That cannot happen.

Comment: @SLaks in the interest of being constructive, I'll post the code in a question, and perhaps if you see it, you wouldn't mind helping me out?

Comment: @SLaks here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491894/how-do-i-fix-a-memory-leak-with-sqlcommand-beginexecutenonquery

Answer (score 5):

You should always call the EndExecuteNonQuery() method to prevent leaks.  It may work now but who knows what will happen in future versions of .NET.  The general rule is always follow a BeginExecute... with an EndExecute...

Comment: +1 Begin__() anything should always* have a matching End___().  But for most of these I like the threadpool delegate approach better.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post; just adding my 2c based on our recent (very conclusive) implementation and testing :D

**To answer the OP's questions:**

1. If you don't call EndExecuteNonQuery, BeginExecuteNonQuery will execute the procedure, but the operation will be cancelled as soon as the using clause disposes of your sql connection. Hence this is not plausible.
2. If you call BeginExecuteNonQuery by using a delegate, creating a new thread etc and you do not call EndExecuteNonQuery, chances are good you might get memory leaks depending on what takes place in you stored procedure. (More on this later).
3. Calling an stored procedure and not waiting for the call to complete, as far I our testing went, is not possible. Irrespective of multitasking, something somewhere will have to wait.

**On to our solution:**

Refs: BeginExecuteNonQuery -> BENQ, EndExecuteNonQuery -> EENQ

**Use Case:**

We have a windows service (C#) that makes use of the .Net TPL library. We needed to load data with a stored procedure from one database to another at run time, based on a add hoc request that the service picks up. Our stored procedure had an internal transaction and exception handling with try catch blocks.

**First Try:**

For our first try we implemented a solution found here [MS Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se(v=vs.110).aspx) in this example you will see that MS opts to call BENQ then implements a while loop to block execution and then calls EENQ. This solution was mainly implemented if you don't need a callback method. The problem with this solution is that only BENQ is ignorant to sql connection timeouts. EENQ will timeout. So for a long running query (which is hopefully the reason why you are using BENQ) you will get stuck in the while and once the operation has completed and you call EENQ, you will get an sql timeout connection.

**Second Try:**

For our second try we thought ok so lets call BENQ, then add a while so that we don't close our sql connection and never call EENQ. This worked, until an exception was thrown in our stored procedure. Because we never called EENQ, the operation was never completed and the exception never bubbled up to our code. Hence we were stuck in a loop/thread/memory leak forever.

**Third Try: (The Solution)**

For our third try we thought to call BENQ, then directly after call EENQ. What happened was that EENQ effectively blocked execution in the thread until the operation completed. When an exception occurred in the stored procedure it was caught. When the query ran long EENQ did not throw a timeout exception and in all cases our sql connection object was disposed as well as our thread.

Here are some extracts of our code:

Here we open up a new thread for the method that calls the stored procedure.

```
//Call the load data stored procedure. As this stored procedure can run longer we start it in its own thread.
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ClassName.MethodName(Parameters));
```

This is the code inside the method we use to call the stored procedure.

```
//Because this is a long running stored procedure, we start is up in a new thread.
using (SqlConnection conn = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringName"]].ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        //Create a new instance SqlCommand.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StoredProcedureName"], conn);

        //Set the command type as stored procedure.
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Create input parameters.
        command.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@Param1", SqlDbType.BigInt, Param1));
        command.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@Param2", SqlDbType.BigInt, Param3));
        command.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@Param3", SqlDbType.BigInt, Param3));

        //Open up the sql connection.
        conn.Open();

        //Create a new instance of type IAsyncResult and call the sp   asynchronously.
        IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

         //When the process has completed, we end the execution of the sp.
        command.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //Write to the log.
    }
}
```

I hope this answer save's someone some headache :D We have tested this thoroughly and have not experienced any issues.

Happy coding!

Comment: Just curious, in the third approach, isn't the only parallelism you're getting coming from Task.Factory.StartNew()? Even if you use simple ExecuteNonQuery instead of the Begin and End variants, the execution will effectively be the same, won't it? Because you're just waiting blankly after the call to BENQ. Please correct me if I've misconstrued something.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `using` statements won't be necessary because you should manually close it yourself rather than allowing the syntactic sugar dispose it for you (i.e. at the `}`).
It should be as simple as this to ensure you don't have leaks.

```
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("blahblah;Asynchronous Processing=true;")
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("someProcedureName", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);
            command.BeginExecuteNonQuery((ar) =>
            {
                var cmd = (SqlCommand)ar.AsyncState;
                cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(ar);
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }, command);
        }
    }
```

As you can see the lambda expression that is fired once the command is finished (no matter how long it takes) will do all the closing for you.