# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem versus BeginExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, threadpool

I have a problem at work with a simple insert method occasionally timing out due to a scheduled clean-up task on a database table. This task runs every ten minutes and during its execution my code often records an error in the event log due to 'the wait operation timed out'.

One of the solutions I'm considering is to make the code calling the stored procedure asynchronous, and in order to do this I first started looking at the BeginExecuteNonQuery method.

I've tried using the BeginExecuteNonQuery method but have found that it quite often does not insert the row at all. The code I've used is as follows:

```
SqlConnection conn = daService.CreateSqlConnection(dataSupport.DBConnString);
SqlCommand command = daService.CreateSqlCommand("StoredProc");

try {
    command.Connection = conn;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("page", page);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Customer", customerId);

    conn.Open();

    command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(delegate(IAsyncResult ar) {
        SqlCommand c = (SqlCommand)ar.AsyncState;

        c.EndExecuteNonQuery(ar);
        c.Connection.Close();
    }, command);

} catch (Exception ex) {
     LogService.WriteExceptionEntry(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
} finally {
     command.Connection.Close();
     command.Dispose();
     conn.Dispose();
}
```

Obviously, I'm not expecting an instant insert but I am expecting it to be inserted after five minutes on a low usage development database.

[I've now switched to the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544905/beginexecutenonquery-without-endexecutenonquery), which does do the insert:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
      using (SqlConnection conn = daService.CreateSqlConnection( dataSupport.DBConnString)) {
         using (SqlCommand command = daService.CreateSqlCommand("StoredProcedure")) {
             command.Connection = conn;

             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("page", page);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer", customerId);

             conn.Open();
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
      }
  });
```

**I've got a few questions, some of them are assumptions:**

As my insert method's signature is void, I'm presuming code that calls it doesn't wait for a response. Is this correct?

Is there a reason why BeginExecuteNonQuery doesn't run the stored procedure? Is my code wrong?

Most importantly, if I use the QueueUserWorkItem (or a well-behaved BeginExecuteNonQuery) am I right in thinking this will have the desired result? Which is, that an attempt to run the stored procedure whilst the scheduled task is running will see the code executing after the task completes, rather than its current timing out?

**Edit**

This is the version I'm using now in response to the comments and answers I've received.

```
SqlConnection conn = daService.CreateSqlConnection(
              string.Concat("Asynchronous Processing=True;",
              dataSupport.DBConnString));
SqlCommand command = daService.CreateSqlCommand("StoredProc");

command.Connection = conn;

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("page", page);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer", customerId);

conn.Open();
command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(delegate(IAsyncResult ar) {
      SqlCommand c = (SqlCommand)ar.AsyncState;

      try {
          c.EndExecuteNonQuery(ar);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
           LogService.WriteExceptionEntry(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
      } finally {
          c.Connection.Close();
          c.Dispose();
          conn.Dispose();
      }

 }, command);
```

Comment: Hi Royi, I've added the asp.net tag. Thank!

Comment: The BeginExecute code closes the connection but does not open it. Show how you call it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've added the code to explain this.

Comment: A proper solution would involve Command.EndExecuteNonQuery(). Just use the ThreadPool.

Comment: You mean like this: c.EndExecuteNonQuery(ar); where c is the SqlCommand object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason why BeginExecuteNonQuery doesn't run the stored
>   procedure? Is my code wrong?

Probably you didn't add the `Asynchronous Processing=True` in the connection string.

Also - there could be a situation that when the reponse from sql is ready - the asp.net response has already sent.

that's why you need to use :  [Page.RegisterASyncTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (+AsyncTimeout)

(if you use webform  asynchronous pages , you should add in the page directive : `Async="True"`)

p.s. this line in :

`System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is dangerouse in asp.net apps. you should take care that the response is not already sent.

Comment: You are correct I didn't use Asynchronous Processing=True in my connection string. As regards the Page.RegisterAsyncTask I don't think I need this. I'm using a HttpHandler, not a WebForm. Also, I'm not waiting for a response from the SQL. I'm just doing the insert.

Comment: HttpHandler , so you should use IhttpAsyncHandler

Comment: Hi, I've tried using the BeginExecuteNonQuery form but have again found that it is not reliable. As I've said it seems as though it doesn't run at all. I'm running the code via a test.